# possible to compile python.exe without Visual Studio, with MinGw

Tags: python, c++, c, visual-studio, mingw

I am trying to achieve things laid out on this page:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/26/cpython-embeddable-zip-file/

The code I am trying to compile is just this:

```
#include "Python.h"

int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

In VisualStudio 15 I have to add the python/include and link to the python libs directories in the project and also add:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

and then it compiles and works fine.  I'm just curious, is it possible to do this with mingw, or another open source C/C++ compiler?

If I place a file `my_python.cpp` which contains the following:

```
#include "include/Python.h"

int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

in the root directory of a fresh 32-bit python 3.5 install (windows 7 x64), cd to that directory and try to run:

`gcc my_python.cpp -Llibs -lpython35 -o my_python.exe`
I get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

Any way to fix this, get it running without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

The error is unrelated to Python. `wmain` is Visual Studio specific. GCC does not treat `wmain` as entry point, it just sits there as a function which never gets called.

GCC requires `main` or `WinMain` as entry point. If neither of those entry points is found, then the compiler will complain. So let's just use `main` as entry point.

`Py_Main` presumably expects wide character string input. `CommandLineToArgvW` will always provide that. Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "include/Python.h"

int main()
{
    int argc;
    wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW( GetCommandLineW(), &argc );
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

If you still get the same error, just provide `WinMain` entry point to make it happy

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "include/Python.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    int argc;
    wchar_t** argv = CommandLineToArgvW( GetCommandLineW(), &argc );
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

Also note, `*.lib` files are usually for Visual Studio. GCC version expects library names with `*.a` extension.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to respond.  I did try this, and am getting the error " undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Main'.  I think this is related to your comment about .a versus .lib files.  I have used the pexports and dlltool to make .a files, but so far have been unable to make the error go away.  I will update further if I can figure it out